# spring-integraton: Initiate a transaction after an Aggregator

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have to transactionally process some group of files aggregating them by their name:
just say I have input files named like this: `A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2, ...`

I need to process them grouped in List like these:

`[A1, A2], [B1, B2], [C1, C2]...`

I made a common transactional chain with an FTP inboundAdapter, an aggregator and my custom processor and it works perfectly except from one detail.

When the processing of a List fail, only the single File that triggered the exception is handled by the rollback SpEL, while I'd want to handle the exception for the list of files it belongs to.

What I basically (think) I need is something like this:

```
+--+  +--+  +--+  +--+  +--+  +--+                       +------+  +------+  +------+
|A1|  |A2|  |B1|  |B2|  |C1|  |C2|     |aggregator| ->   |A1, A2|  |B1, B2|  |C1, C2|
+--+  +--+  +--+  +--+  +--+  +--+                       +------+  +------+  +------+
                            
                                                       \-----------------------------/
                                                              transaction's scope
```

If I initiate the transaction only after the aggregator, the SpEL expression would sees only List messages and not single File, right?

What I don't know how to do it, is initiate a transaction without using a Poller in the middle of the chain, that would introduce a delay.

Any hint?

Thank you!

EDIT: I've solved adding an Advice to the processing handle but I'm not 100% sure it's the "correct" solution

Comment: Yes; that is the correct solution; I suggest you add an answer (and accept it) showing your revised code.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by Gary here's the solution I adopted:

```java
return IntegrationFlows
  .from(Ftp.inboundAdapter(ftpSessionFactory)
     // my FTP inbound adapter
  )
  .aggregate(a ->
     //  my aggregator strategy     
  )
  .handle(myAggregatedMessageProcessor(), c -> c.advice(myProcessorAdvice()))
  .get();
```

the relevant part being `c -> c.advice(processErrorAdvice())`

and I also configured the Advice like this:

```java
  @Bean
  Advice myProcessorAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
        advice.setSuccessChannelName("successChannel");
        advice.setFailureChannelName("failedChannel");
        
        // this catches the Exceptions
        advice.setTrapException(true);
        return advice;
    }
```